# Is it possible to run 2 threads in the same time continuously in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I try to run a thread that is calculating different data and when the server call is made to serve data.

What i do not understand is why the program not pass to call sending and receiving after thread start

```
class FuncThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, image_model):  
    self.image_model = image_model
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    image_model = self.image_model
    while True:

def sending_ receiving(): 
  while true: 

image_model = init()
thread1 = FuncThread(image_model)  
thread1.setDaemon(True)
thread1.start() # this should not affect the course of executing order 
sending_and_reciveing()   - this is contiuously listening client request
```

thread.start is calling run method that is a while true loop that run continuously .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I correct the typos in your code, it works well on my machine.

```
import time
import threading

class FuncThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, image_model):  
    self.image_model = image_model
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    image_model = self.image_model
    while True:
        print('run')
        time.sleep(1)

def sending_and_receiving(): 
  while True: 
      print('sending_and_receiving')
      time.sleep(1)

image_model = 'test'
thread1 = FuncThread(image_model)  
thread1.setDaemon(True)
thread1.start()
sending_and_receiving()
```